# Podspec dependency doesn't work by configuration

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I'm developing a React Native Native Module on iOS that relies on a third party framework (dependency). I've the need to link such dependency in its own two variations (Debug and Release).

Here is the Podspec of my Native Module:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "RNModule"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.summary      = "My Native Module"
  s.license      = "UNLICENSED"
  s.ios.deployment_target = '13.0'
  s.source_files  = "ios/**/*.{h,m}"
  s.dependency "React-Core"
  s.dependency 'ThirdPartyFramework-Debug', configurations => :debug
  s.dependency 'ThirdPartyFramework', configurations => :release
end
```

I defined ThirdPartyFramework to be compiled for Debug and Release configurations, [as per documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency).
Unfortunately the `pod install` run of the parent app ends up in the following error:

"[!] The 'Pods-cornernative' target has frameworks with conflicting names: thirdpartyframework.xcframework."

- I'm using cocoapods version 1.11.3
- If I integrate ThirdPartyFramework as myParentApp's pod dependency (Podfile) as following

```
pod 'ThirdPartyFramework-Debug', :configurations => :debug  
pod 'ThirdPartyFramework', :configurations => :release
```

It works like a charm.

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!